# Rails wraps fields with errors by div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, forms

How can I stop Rails to change my code when validation isn't passed.

Every time rails wraps my field with

```
<div class='field_with_error'>...</div>
```

I can edit `fields_with_error` class

```
.fields_with_error{ display: inline }
```

which works, but it is hacky

Comment: Is there seriously no way to prevent this w/o catching it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its fine. Use the CSS thing instead of doing this.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  "<span class='field_error'>#{html_tag}</span>"
end
```

Which I feel is more hacky :)

Comment: it is more hacky, true :) But I hope that there is a simple solution, like just turn off rails to change my code

Comment: How is rails "changing your code"?  If rails is wrapping it, then you are using rails helpers.  Don't use those helpers if you don't want it, or write your own form builder helpers.

Comment: Did not work for me, it just displayed it as text, then this ```config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  html_tag
} ``` worked for me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t).
Note. I am using rails 5

Answer (score 5):

I use this in environment.rb. Even more hacky ;-)

```
#
# Fix annoying <div class="fieldsWithError"> wrapping after validation
# http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/3587
#

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  msg = instance.error_message 

  if html_tag =~ /<(input|textarea|select)[>]+class=/
    class_attribute = html_tag =~ /class=['"]/ 
    html_tag.insert(class_attribute + 7, "error ") 
  elsif html_tag =~ /<(input|textarea|select)/
    first_whitespace = html_tag =~ /\s/ 
    html_tag[first_whitespace] = " class='error' "
  end 

  html_tag
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use jQuery to do it. Still feel like a hack but its working.

```
$('.field_with_errors input').unwrap();
```

Comment: Indeed, this can help in very exceptional cases. Thanks!

Comment: If you have users who aren't running JS they will have different behavior.  Using JS for this is overkill.