# How do you customize Ruby on Rails validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Currently when there is a validation error, a `div` with `class="field_with_errors"` gets rendered in my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <input id="user_email" type="text" value="tom@test.com" name="user[email]">
  </div>
  <input id="user_password" type="password" value="mypass" size="30" name="user[password]">
  <input id="user_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit">
</form>
```

Without the use of an additional gem and in a Rails 3 environment, is there a way to modify how the validation error is rendered? For example, I want the validation error `div` to be rendered after the `input` tag with the error:

```
<input id="user_email" type="text" value="tom@test.com" name="user[email]"><div class="field_with_errors"></div>
```

Also, is there a way to render a specific error? If it was an email error, then render the `div` after the input textbox and produce a "Re-enter your email" message.

(Most of the searches I have done so far use gems as the solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You can remove the field_with_errors wrapper by overriding `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`.It can be done by putting this in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| "#{html_tag}".html_safe }
```

Refer

[Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

2.You can display error message on specific field.

```
<input id="user_email" type="text" value="tom@test.com" name="user[email]">
<% if @user.errors.on(:email).present? %>
   <span class="error">Re-enter your email(or)<%= @user.errors.on(:email) %></span>
<% end %>
```

Then in your CSS

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```