# How can I stop Rails from wrapping the label with field_with_errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When saving a form and a field fails validation, I don't want the label to be modified at all.
I don't mind wrapping the input with a div and a class of "field_with_errors", but how can I stop it from wrapping the label as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything in the ActionView::Base documentation about the field_error_proc method, but here is the solution I came up with.  Hopefully this will help others!

```
 ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance| 
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
  else
    html_tag.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Would just add, place this in a file in config/initializers to use.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having for example

```
<%=label "name", :name%>
```

, remove `:name` and have

```
<%=label "name"%>
```

This will stop the wrapping.

Comment: This removes the connection between the `<label>` and the `<input>` field that it is associated with. For example, a general behaviour is that by clicking on the label, it will focus (activate) the input it is connected to.