# Collection does not include prompt after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a collection set that has the days of the month 1 through 31.  I validate in my model.  When the page loads with an :birth error the prompt "Day" is no longer in my drop down box.

In my view

```
<%= f.label :birth %>
<%= f.collection_select(:birth_day, 1..31, :to_i, :to_i , :prompt=>'Day') %>
```

In my Model

```
validate :validate_dates

def validate_dates  
  b_month = self.birth_month.to_i

  if (b_month == 4 || b_month == 6 || b_month == 9 || b_month == 11)
    if (self.birth_day == 31)
      self.errors.add(:birth, "is invalid")
    end
  end
end
```

Generated Source - Before Error

```
<label for="individual_birth">Birth</label>
<select id="individual_birth_day" name="individual[birth_day]">
  <option value="">Day</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  ....
 </select>
```

Generated Source - After Error

```
<div class="field_with_errors"><label for="individual_birth">Birth</label></div>
<select id="individual_birth_day" name="individual[birth_day]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  ....
  <option value="31" selected="selected">31</option>
 </select>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  I need the prompt in the drop down since Day is not a required field. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML for that element before and after.

Comment: I added the generated HTML.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `field_error_proc` by placing this code in `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  "#{html_tag}".html_safe 
}
```

another example overriding `field_error_proc` https://gist.github.com/1464315

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268106/643500

If that does not do it, look into that function and what it is doing that causes the `:prompt=>'Day'` to disappear.

**Edit:**

After more testing the problem appears to be when the user already selects a value and tries to submit the form.  This causes all other errors to appear while still holding the new selected value of the `collection_select` therefore the prompt is omitted (There is already a value)

To solve this change your `collection_select` to a `select` with `options_from_collection_for_select`

Something like

```
<%= f.select "element_name", options_from_collection_for_select(@my_select_collection, :my_value_method, :my_text_method, 0), {:prompt => "Day"} %> # 0 or nothing (holds default)
```

This way we set the default value to always 0 or leave it empty for `nil`.  This way we guarantee that there is no valid value to be defaulted (If defaulted to valid value prompt will not show)

The other way is to use `:include_blank`, but that will not have 'Day'.  That works for your scenario without changing anything.  Just replace `:prompt => 'Day'` with `:include_blank => true`.  There will always be an empty option.  You can reset the blank to a value with JS.

Comment: D3mon - I tried exactly what you suggested and prompt "Day" disappeared when the page refreshed.  `<%= f.select :birth_day, options_from_collection_for_select(1..31, :to_i, :to_s , 0), {:prompt=>"Day"} %>`.  It's unfortunately a little worse.  Now when the error displays on the page, the drop down changes to the first entry - "1" and the prompt is gone.  I'm using Rails 3.2.6.