# Devise Error Messages (Customization)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So i've got Devise working quite as it should, although I've mustered up few pet-peeves with the standard look of the gem.

I've sorted out most of them but the last one that I can clearly identify is the red border when there is an error message. I've uploaded a screenshot to illustrate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e7H6.png.

How can one go about getting rid of that? or changing it to white, or blue or something?

So far the CSS code looks like:

```
.field_with_errors {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
margin: auto auto;
}
```

I've already tried background: white; and background-color: white; to no avail.

Comment: Can you open firebug and check the styles applied to the error div. You can right click on the element which has the red border in firefox, and say 'inspect with firebug' and check it.

Comment: Funny you say that, that is exactly what i did to find "field_with_errors". Just checked again and it says the following: .field_with_errors {
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
    padding: 2px;
}

Comment: I've got it! Thanks for that input, I went back to look at the source with firebug and found out where that css file was .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the error message add following config to your `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| html_tag.html_safe }
```

To customize it further have a look at this SO thread [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)