# Can “field-with-errors” be attached to the parent of the input tag that raises the error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, field-with-errors

So I have an input element like this.  The wrapping element is about, you know, a visual thing.

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input class="blah-blah" />
</div>
```

When the `<input>` contains the error, it'll be like this:

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <div class="field-with-errors">
    <input class="blah-blah" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But what I want to do is:

```
<div class="input-wrap field-with-errors">
  <input class="blah-blah" />
</div>
```

I found this page, it's very close to my question

[Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

Now I know I can throw

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
   "#{html_tag}".html_safe
}
```

to avoid making a wrapping tag around the `<input>` tag that has an error on.  But what I really wanna do is, again, adding "field-with-errors" class on the direct parent of the `<input>` tag.  Can I do that?  Does ActionView hold the tree structure of DOM Nodes?

Comment: Have you found a solution ? It seems like (for a beginner like me) imposible to achieve. Probably another helper as wrapper is required

Comment: There are some related questions on the side menu. There seems no straightforward solution for this yet? I dunno. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t offers a good hint. If you can't change the template from the helper function, maybe adding a data-attribute and add the class name to the parent by JS? It sounds terrible but it may be one way to do it…

Comment: Hello @beatak , despite it was a while, have you seen [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t/8380400#8380400) from that SO? It seems that he actually managed to do that by manipulating at the string level..

Answer (score -2):

You can put the code for handling errors wherever you like, just call it as a block on the instance variable, for example

```
if @instance.errors.any?
  <div class="field with errors">
  @instance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    <p><%= msg %></p>
  end
end
```

If you user this a lot, it's good to pull it out into a helper and pass in the instance variable as a parameter.