# Override 'field_with_errors' on a per view basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I know you can override `ActionView::Base` via the methods posted in this question:

[Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

However, I'm wondering how to disable it on a per view basis?  In other words, I want the default behavior site wide except for views I designate.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in the view itself

```
<% unless @user.errors["email"].blank? &>
     @user.errors["email"] = "your custom message"
 <% end %>
```