# Why after submit a form and validated the data, the form's style went wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby on Rails.

My view's source is :

```
<dl class="multi_list">
  <dt>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    <%= f.label :subject %>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I can see the result from browser like this:

```
■Subject
```

But after I submit the form, and runs the validate source. The form in my browser went:

```
■
Subject
```

Why?

---

I know the answer:

[Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

Comment: could I see more code? Include the whole form block.

Comment: Could you show us what the generated HTML and CSS are in each case?

Comment: need to know what CSS is assigned to `<dl>` and `<dt>` as well as the content of CSS class `multi_list`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style for the `"dl.multi_list dt div.field_with_errors"` and `"dl.multi_list dt div.field_with_errors labels"` .