# <Rails> Page format falls apart when rendering

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, render

I created a sample app to play around with rails. I'm having trouble with the page format of my site when a page is rendered. The text fields moves out of place from it's previous position and the format is just ruined. Please see the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t) and just click the button and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Here is my controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @books = Book.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @books = Book.new(book_params)

    if @books.save
      redirect_to new_book_path, :flash => { :success => "Book Added"}
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :genre, :no_of_items)
    end  

end
```

here my views/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Books#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/books/new.html.erb</p>

<% flash.each do |key, value|%>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group row-fluid form-inline">
    <%= form_for @books do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_message' %>
        <p>
            <div class="fields">
                <%= f.label :title, "Title:"%>
                <%= f.text_field :title %><br/><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="fields">
                <%= f.label :author, "Author:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :author %><br/><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="fields">
                <%= f.label :no_of_items, "No. of Items:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :no_of_items%><br/><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="fields">
                <%= f.label :genre, "Genre:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :genre%><br/><br/>

            </div>


            <p>
                <%= submit_tag "Add book"%>
            </p>
        </p>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me tell what's happening and a fix for this? Thanks.

**ANSWER:**
Hi everyone thanks for the advises but I found out through [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t) thread how to fix this problem. I can't answer my question within 6 hours so I'll answer this after the restriction has ended.

Comment: can you not just tell us whats happening?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `<br/>`?

Comment: @sevenseacat The input field is going to the next line.

Comment: @Patrick Tried to remove the <br/> tags, but it just removed the new line after each input fields. The input fields are still out of line with my label.

sevenseacat i'll edit my post, it's just a little hard for me to describe exactly in words the problem.

Comment: so dont describe it in words, describe it with pictures, or describe it with a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t) how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each label and input is being wrapped in an additional `div` element with the class `field_with_errors`.

You could give the `field_with_errors` class an `display: inline-block;` property, or try formatting your form like the example in the Bootstrap docs.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try and clean up. I'll be back if I have anymore questions or if I find this the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

There is some unnecessary formatting you've added to the `new.html.erb`. One of rails' strength is the minimal amount of work created with helpers such as `form_for`

```
<h1>Books#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/books/new.html.erb</p>

<% flash.each do |key, value|%>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group row-fluid form-inline">
        <%= form_for @books do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_message' %>

            <%= f.label :title, "Title:"%>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>

            <%= f.label :author, "Author:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :author %>


            <%= f.label :no_of_items, "No. of Items:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :no_of_items %>

            <%= f.label :genre, "Genre:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :genre %>


            <%= f.submit "Add book" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you don't align your input fields correctly, i see some margin-left (for the first filed is 60px, for the second is 45px ...) so i suggest you to remove this css `margin-left` for your input and add this to your label:

```
label {
        width:150px;    /*Or however much space you need for the form’s labels*/
        float:left;
}
```

this is a quick [tutorial](http://www.robozen.com/css-magic-align-form-fields-without-tables/) about how to align your fields

then after you submit your form with empty fields, rails will trigger some errors, and wrap each field (also label) which has error with `div class="field_with_errors` like this:  `<div class="field_with_errors"><input type="text"..... /></div>` : this **div** will **return** your field to the next line so if you would that your fields still inline you just add this css to your css file :

```
.field_with_errors{
     display: inline;
}
```