# .field_with_errors messes up bootstrap styled form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap 3's grid system to layout a simple sign up form. However, if a validation in Rails fails, the added div with the class "field_with_errors" messes up my layout.

Here's how a line in my form usually looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="user_secondary_email">Secondary email</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input class="form-control" id="user_secondary_email" name="user[secondary_email]" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When the validation fails the currently applied style looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="user_primary_email">Primary email</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="form-control" id="user_primary_email" name="user[primary_email]" type="text" value="" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did some research and as far as I understand, this is how the code should look like:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="user_secondary_number">Secondary number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="user_secondary_number" name="user[secondary_number]" type="text" />
        </div>
   </div>
```

What I don't understand is how I can get application to add the additional class to the correct html tag?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What kind of Form Builder are you using? Rails form_for? Simple Form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably haven't defined `field_with_errors` properly. In your css you should have code like this:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

Apart from that, your app behaves like it should. The code you expected (third code block of your question) is not correct, because none of the fields would be styled with `field_with_errors`-class. The problem lies in your css file. So if my solution doesn't work, post that file.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction - I had used scaffolding to create some of my code. And the scaffold.css seemed to overrule the bootstrap.css and my custom.css. Since I didn't need it, deleting scaffold.css solved the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: This works, but it still breaks rounded corners when you use addons for inputs (for example, with calendar icons etc.).

Comment: For bootstrap 4, the class to extend with is `.has-danger`.

Comment: [`.has-danger` does not work for Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46179078/2948889) anymore. If you do [server-side validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#server-side), you need to set `.is-invalid`, `.is-valid` or `.invalid-feedback` from your code (at least until helpers are updated). You can also check [here](https://jasoncharnes.com/bootstrap-4-rails-fields-with-errors/) for initializer based approach.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I added this to `config/application.rb`

```rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag.html_safe
end
```

I'm using bootstrap 5.1 (and rails 7) but it will probably work for other versions too.

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/s-zwrg/remove-rails-field_with_errors-wrapper