# Bootstrap styling for .fields_with_errors not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

When the form is submitted and there are errors: I want to have the offending fields highlighted in bootstrap error/alert styling.  Out of the box: Bootstrap does not style the conventional `fields_with_errors` class that gets applied to the failed-validation fields in rails forms.

In the past [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161622/field-with-errors-messes-up-bootstrap-styled-form) I have simply added this:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

And the offending form fields were highlighted with bootstrap error/alert styling as desired.  However, this is not working in my current rails project, and I am not sure what I am missing.

I'm sure I am missing something simple:

```
#application.css.scss

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-datepicker3";


.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

```
#relevant gems in Gemfile

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>=3.3.6'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1.1'
```

HTML of relevant form fields before submission (both fields fail validations):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="expense_duration_start_date">Start Date</label><br>
  <input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name="expense_duration[start_date]" id="expense_duration_start_date" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="expense_duration_end_date">End Date</label><br>
  <input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name="expense_duration[end_date]" id="expense_duration_end_date" />
</div>
```

HTML of form fields after form-submission:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="expense_duration_start_date">Start Date</label></div><br>
  <div class="field_with_errors"><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name="expense_duration[start_date]" id="expense_duration_start_date" /></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="expense_duration_end_date">End Date</label></div><br>
  <div class="field_with_errors"><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" name="expense_duration[end_date]" id="expense_duration_end_date" /></div>
</div>
```

So the `.field_with_errors` class is getting applied, but it is just not being styled, and I do not know why the css of `@extend .has-error;` is not working.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below.  Biggest thing was to ensure all relevant classes were included. Specifically: the `form-group` class, the `control-label` class and the `form-control` class:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :start_date, "Start Date", class: "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, data: {provide: 'datepicker'}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
     <%= f.label :end_date, "End Date", class: "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :end_date, data: {provide: 'datepicker'}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```