# .field_with_errors in Rails breaks Twitter Bootstrap 3 input styles with addons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have HAML

```
...
.row
  .col-md-3.form-group
    = offer.label :departure_date, "Abfahrt"
    .input-group.date
      = offer.text_field :departure_date, class: "form-control", readonly: ""
      %span.input-group-addon
        %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
...
```

that generates such HTML (datepicker markup)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <label for="offer_departure_date">Abfahrt</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input class="form-control" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="offer[departure_date]" id="offer_departure_date">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I get error, Rails wraps `label` and `input` with a div having class `field_with_errors`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="offer_departure_date">Abfahrt</label></div>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="form-control" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" name="offer[departure_date]" id="offer_departure_date"></div>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my application.css.sass I've extended `field_with_errors` with the following:

```
.field_with_errors 
  @extend .has-error
```

After that most simple fields became normal styling accept of this datepicker: the input field lost its rounded corners, addon part remained default (even not red). In combination with other fields this looks ugly. How can that be fixed? Here is screenshot with this field - http://minus.com/lbeNYx1yXyqk4C

Comment: What's the CSS for `.date` ?

Comment: `.date` has no css. That is just some service class used for javascript events, I think. Actually, I use this gem https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails for calendar

Comment: `.has-error` goes on the `.form-group`, hence why your `@extend` isn't working; it's not the right position in the DOM. Try killing the field_with_errors wrapper div altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5268106/3342739

Comment: I thought about that. But in that case I have to refuse from build-in functionality of fields highlighting :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following css to fix the issue

```
.field_with_errors {
    display: block !important;
}
.field_with_errors > .datetimepicker {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `.datetimepicker`?