# How field_with_errors div Gets Added in a Form When Validations Fail Within fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is clear to me that when a validation fails in a form: what happens is the `errors` hash associated to your object gains a new key which is magically mapped to that object's invalid `attribute`.  That key's `value` is the relevant error message for that invalidation.

The above is all explained nicely in the [Working with Validation Errors Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors)

This next part is what does not make sense to me.  Magically: rails appears to somehow look at the keys in your errors hash, map those to the appropriate form labels and inputs, and then wraps those invalid form labels and inputs with a `<div class="field_with_errors"> ... </div>`.

I am trying to figure out how that magic works.

To be more specific: I am wondering how rails is able to map the `field_with_errors` appropriately when there are `fields_for` present in a form for a `has_many` association.

Example: Say I have the following associations:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_emails
end

# models/user_email.rb
class UserEmail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :email_text
end
```

I then have a `user`form that has `fields_for` for **5** different nested `user_email` records.  Let us say two of those `user_emails` are invalid:

- The form will re-render, and magically the `fields_with_errors` div *only gets applied* to those two invalid `user_email` records as opposed to *ALL* of the `user_email` records in the form.

How does rails do this?  I cannot find the documentation on this, or find any resources online in regards to the magic that is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects are passed through the `field_error_proc` one by one, so each is `UserEmail` is evaluated separately. The default proc specification is defined here:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7da8d76206271bdf200ea201f7e5a49afb9bc9e7/actionview/lib/action_view/base.rb#L144 as:

```
@@field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe }
```

This is called by `ActiveModelInstanceTag`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/active_model_helper.rb#L28 with:

```
Base.field_error_proc.call(html_tag, self)
```

Note that `self` here refers to an individual `UserEmail` object being evaluated. More information on this proc is available at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/09436fb6d6d188739b40ef120b4344106d81caf9/guides/source/configuring.md#configuring-action-view and at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c3a99eeca07f602bb1e5659656e8eab0a4eacfe/guides/source/active_support_core_extensions.md#cattr_reader-cattr_writer-and-cattr_accessor.

There's no magic at work; it evaluates all the models.